# Can JavaScript message queues be blocked?

Tags: javascript, message-queue, event-loop

JavaScript runtime environment (e.g. browser) has at least two thread.

1. JavaScript thread (call stack + message queue + event loop)
2. Web API thread (for ajax, DOM, setTimeout, etc)

If JavaScript thread is running some function, Web API thread can enqueue message(callback) to message queue at same time?

- If possible, message queue is included in JavaScript thread, how can is possible?
- If impossible, Web API thread is waiting for enqueueing?

Comment: _"has at least two threads."_ - according to whom?

Comment: Read this: https://dev.to/bbarbour/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd

Comment: ...and this: https://javascript.info/event-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended reading:

- https://dev.to/bbarbour/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd
- https://javascript.info/event-loop
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

> Can JavaScript message queues be blocked?

In a word, and as far as you're concerned: **no**.

> JavaScript runtime environment (e.g. browser) has at least two thread.

This is incorrect: JavaScript (formally, ECMAScript) is [conceptually single-threaded](https://dev.to/bbarbour/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd): within a single scripting-context there is *at most* a single thread executing *user-code* (i.e. JavaScript).

Of course, within a web-browser all the scripts in different contexts (i.e. browser-tabs, extensions, service-workers) will be running concurrently but are all isolated from each other in their own script context: there is no mutable shared-state (yes, there are exceptions but they all concern legacy things like synchronous cross-frame DOM access, which no-one should be using anymore: use `postMessage` instead).

> 1. JavaScript thread (call stack + message queue + event loop)
> 2. Web API thread (for ajax, DOM, `setTimeout`, etc)

This is also incorrect: when the *single* JavaScript "thread" returns from user JavaScript code (be it back into the browser's engine after finishing execution of the anonymous top-level script/function, or if there's an uncaught error, or if the current function finished synchronous execution with no user-code to return to (e.g. inside an `async` function or after a `Promise` is obtained but before its `resolve` is invoked) then everything is handled by the browser, with its internal, native (i.e. non-JS) code, which is all [a black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box): you can't see into it, *by design*, because you don't need to.

> If JavaScript thread is running some function, Web API thread can enqueue message(callback) to message queue at same time?

The "Web API thread" you're referring to does not exist - but *in principle*, **yes**: the browser's native code handling `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest` can (but is not required to) run concurrently with any exectuting user-JavaScript... though any callback or task won't be executed until the single JavaScript thread returns back to the browser engine.

> If possible, message queue is included in JavaScript thread, how can is possible?

Because browsers *host* a JavaScript engine and present an environment to it, which they have complete control over, including choosing exactly how to implement browser-provided JS functionality like `fetch`.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing answer. Thanks a lot!